# Linear equation in Field

Tags: discrete-mathematics, field-theory

[image: Question]
[image: Solution]
I have a question on solving linear equation in field. I can't seem to understand how it works by checking the solution. Can someone explain to me bit more on how to solve the equation. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this answers exactly what you're asking, but this is how I see it: as in any field
$$16(x-6)=15\iff x-6=16^{-1}\cdot 15\iff x=16^{-1}\cdot 15+6.$$
Simply, it happens that $\;16^{-1}=6$, $\;6\cdot15=14=-5$ and $-5+6=1$.

Comment: i am not sure on how to solve this equation when there is fields involved. Do you mind to explain what roughly this question is asking? Thank you so much!

Comment: Well this question is asking to find the solution(s) of the equation, as stated explicitly. It's the same as in   $\mathbf R$ or $\mathbf C$: wwhen you solve $ax+b=c$, saying $x=\dfrac{c-b}a$,  you're actually saying that $x=a^{-1}(c-b)$. Isn't it clear?

Comment: oh i get it, thank you for your explanation